In Angular version 18 sourceMap is not working
I am using Angular 18 version. In browser, I am mot getting error or console log line number of typescript file in console panel in browser development tool.
I have checked sourceMap value is set to true in angular.json file and the same is also set to true in tsconfig file as well
Is there any additional settings I need to set to make this work?
angular.json file

package.json file


For me it works in a fresh Angular 18 project. Please provide more details, and ideally a minimal reproduction.

@chetan please share the angular.json and what environment you are using to check

I have used Angular cli version 18.0.6 and created project without standalone and thereafter I have generated environment variables.

@chetan angular.json?

@naren not able to add angular.json file in the comment, but here is the screen shot added in the question

Please refresh the page. I have updated the image.

I found the issue. This is an issue in the Chrome Browser settings. "Javascript source maps" was not enabled.
I enabled this setting by selecting the checkbox, reload the page and its start working. Thanks for your support and help.
Link for how to enable source maps in Settings?


Your default configuration is "production".
Verify you are actually running the "development" configuration, which has sourceMaps: true.
You can accomplish this in two ways:

Run build/serve with configuration flag: ng serve --configuration development
Change the defaultConfiguration to development (be sure to change your production build command to pass the production configuration as above)


Hi @Ryan - Thanks for the reply. I did change in the file and changed default value to development. Still not working. I have also added image of script defind in the package.json file.

I was trying running application in Chrome browser and facing this issue but now I just tried this in Edge it is showing me line number of typescript file in the browser development tool. I think there may be a  some kind of settings changed in the chrome browser. Trying to figuring out.

In Chrome, there is filtering on the Console tab.
Along the left side, do you have "Messages" or "Errors" selected? If not it will hide the errors.

Hi @Ryan - The issue was because of Chrome Browser settings.  Its working fine now. I posted the solution in the below comment.

Awesome, glad you got it working
